# How to subscribe the event of becoming LEADER in Akka Cluster Singleton Pattern

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

As a instance member of Akka Singleton cluster, how to subscribe the event of becoming LEADER in Akka Cluster Singleton Pattern.

application.conf as follow:

```
akka {
actor {
  provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  deployment {
    /singleton/registerService/workerRouter {
      router = consistent-hashing-pool
      nr-of-instances = 100
      cluster {
        enabled = on
        max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 3
        allow-local-routees = on
        use-role = registers
      }
    }
  }
}
remote {
  log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
  netty.tcp {
    hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 0
  }
}

cluster {
  seed-nodes = [
    "akka.tcp://PashRegister@127.0.0.1:2051",
    "akka.tcp://PashRegister@127.0.0.1:2052"]

  auto-down-unreachable-after = 5s

  roles = ["registers"]
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of the cluster singleton is that it will be started on your behalf - so when such actor starts it is "leader" (as in "running the singleton").

Answer (score 0):

If question is to be notified when the leader changes (say when the first singleton that started has been downed), then the only way I found to know who is the leader is to do the following:

- Have an actor subscribing to all MemberEvents
- Whenever a MemberUp or MemberRemoved event happens:

  - update a sorted list of members of the role the singleton has (order by Member.ageOrdering)
  - the first element of this list is the current leader

Basically I am re-implemeting the logic behind choosing the new leader.
Hope that helps.